# Ignorar un parámetro de la URL en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Me encuentro el siguiente problema, tengo un sitio **example.com** hecho en wordpress. Actuamente tengo una página **example.com/contact** que muestra la información de contacto. Quiero personalizar la información que se muestra ahí, de forma que pueda acceder a **example.com/page1/contact** o **example.com/page2/contact** y me muestre información diferente.
Crearé un plugin que haga uso de la información proporcionada como primer parámetro, pero de momento wordpress elimina automáticamente ese parámetro, de forma que  al ingresar a **example.com/page1/contact** soy redirigido a **example.com/contact**. Si no logro evitar que wordpress me deje de quitar ese parámetro, no podré hacer que plugin funcione. Alguna idea de cómo puedo hacerlo?.
Agrego que /page1/ se mantendrá durante toda la navegación del usuario, es decir, si va a otra página como /about-us, la url debe ser **example.com/page1/about-us**.
**-- EDITO --**
Mi .htaccess actual es el siguiente

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

#Mi intento por ignorar el parámetro
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$2 [C]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

# END WordPress

El parámetro planeo obtenerlo a través de la url

Comment: Deberías **[edit]** tu pregunta agregando lo que tengas en el archivo .htaccess, y aclarando cómo deberías recibir ese parámetro con la página

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, agregué mi .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución para esto, tuve que crear una rewrite rule pero en wordpress, que me ignorara el primer parámetro

```
add_rewrite_rule("([A-Za-z0-9]*)/contact$", "index.php?page_id=9", "top");
```

La mayor desventaja es que tengo que indicar el id de la página a la cuál quiero se dirija, pero soluciona bien mi problema. Si alguien quiere contribuir cómo hacer esto dinámico, serán aceptados los comentarios